# ClickOnce sending parameter is not working

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, clickonce

I want to send parameters to ClickOnce and show in a WinForm `Label`.

All settings are correct in my opinion.

[This is my ClickOnce settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nYxvL.png)

[localhost ClickOnce look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dHR5P.png)

What is the problem ? I did not find any solution about this situation. How can I send parameter to ClickOnce?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should pass the parameters using `QueryString`.

Then in the application, try reading the query string. To do so, you should open the application using a link like `http://servername/WindowsApp1.application?username=joeuser`. Then you can get the values in your application and use them in your forms.

To do so, add `System.Web` reference to your application and then use the following property to your `Program` class and use `Program.QueryString` wherever you need:

```
private static NameValueCollection queryString;
public static NameValueCollection QueryString
{
    get
    {
        if (queryString == null)
        {
            NameValueCollection nameValueTable = new NameValueCollection();
            if (ApplicationDeployment.IsNetworkDeployed)
            {
                var q = ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.ActivationUri.Query;
                nameValueTable = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(q);
            }
            queryString = nameValueTable;
        }
        return queryString;
    }
}
```

**Note:**

- You should make sure that you have set *Allow URL parameters to be passed to application* to true in publish options. (Screenshots show that you have set it correctly.)
- To learn more, take a look at [How to: Retrieve Query String Information in an Online ClickOnce Application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/how-to-retrieve-query-string-information-in-an-online-clickonce-application)

Comment: Note that this doesn't work at all unless the **Allow URL parameters to be passed to the application** option is enabled.

Comment: @WiktorZychla Yes that's correct and the OP has set this parameter to true.

Comment: I added that to the answer as well, to make sure future readers will not miss that :)

Comment: @RezaAgahei: that was exactly the point of my comment - to not to let future readers miss that important detail. Regards.

Comment: @WiktorZychla Yes, your comment is important for future readers and that's why I mentioned it the answer. Thanks for the feedback:)

Comment: Thanks Reza , and i found google chrome extension and its working :)

 (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/clickonce-for-google-chro/kekahkplibinaibelipdcikofmedafmb)